# How to Return a pre-populated rate from an if, if(and statement

Tags: if-statement, return

I'm trying to return a value from a table:

```
Load Amount           USD Conversion    Bps Label   Bps

<=   € 20,000,000.00     $22,746,600.00     25          0.0025
>    € 20,000,000.00     $22,746,600.00     20          0.002
<=   € 60,000,000.00     $68,239,800.00     20          0.002
>    € 60,000,000.00     $68,239,800.00     15          0.0015
```

Where an input will determine which Bps to return.  I've tried the following function without any luck:

> =IF((I25<='Bps Breakdown'!D3,'Bps Breakdown'!F3),IF(AND('Cost Model'!I25>'Bps Breakdown'!D4,'Cost Model'!I25<='Bps Breakdown'!D5),'Bps Breakdown'!F5,IF('Cost Model'!I25>'Bps Breakdown'!D6,'Bps Breakdown'!F6)))

I25 is an input by the user. Please let me know if more detail is needed.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS9r0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have removed the first image as it is not necessary.  You have typed the data in, which is great.  It would be preferred if you did the same with the second image.  I also used the '>' to markup your code as it is not formatted and was hard to read without scrolling.  It would be easier for everyone if you did format and word-wrap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that I didn't need an And statement to complete the thought.  I used this formula to get my result:

> =IF(I25<='Bps Breakdown'!$D$3,'Bps Breakdown'!$F$3,IF('Cost Model'!I25<='Bps Breakdown'!$D$5,'Bps Breakdown'!$F$5,IF('Cost Model'!I25>'Bps Breakdown'!$D$6,'Bps Breakdown'!$F$6)))

Comment: Yes, I will do this going forward.  Thanks for your comments!